# How to relate the number of bosons (fermions) with the number of vertices and external (internal) bosons (fermion) lines?

Tags: feynman-diagrams, quantum-chromodynamics, fermions, bosons

I am following the QCD book: "QCD: Renormalisation for the Practitioner" by  P. Pascual, R. Tarrach. In chapter 3, page 64, equation III.13 they relate the following quantities:

> Let us consider a diagram with $n_i$ vertices of the type associated
>   with $\mathcal{L}_i$, $B_E(B_I)$ being the number of external
>   (internal) Boson lines, $F_E(F_I)$ the number of external (internal)
>   fermion lines and $V=\sum_in_i$ the total number of vertices. The
>   quantities can be related by
>
> \begin{equation}  2B_I + B_E = \sum_i n_i b_i, \qquad 2F_I + F_E =
> > \sum_i n_i f_i \end{equation}

I would like to proof these two relations. I tried to look look at the Feynman diagrams I can produce from the QCD Lagrangian, but have not figured out on how to exactly derive these the above relations.

Could anybody give me an idea or a reference on how to proceed?

Cheers,
Dirk